# JSX how to take counter from loop and display with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a problem with loop and states. How to display states info in loop if I want to union part of state name and number?

In JS file I have constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fruit_1: 'apple',
        fruit_2: 'orange',
        fruit_3: 'bannana',
        fruit_4: 'apple',
    }
}
```

And loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(this.state.fruit_i); 
    {/* Here is a problem. Calls undefined, but if I write this.state.fruit_1 -> displays correctly. */}
    {/* How to union counter with this state name? */}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below. It builds the string you need:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fruit_1: 'apple',
        fruit_2: 'orange',
        fruit_3: 'bannana',
        fruit_4: 'apple',
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(this.state["fruit_" + i]);
}
```

```js
state = {
  fruit_1: 'apple',
  fruit_2: 'orange',
  fruit_3: 'bannana',
  fruit_4: 'apple',
}

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(this.state["fruit_" + i]);
}
```

---

Though I would suggest using an array to store the fruits, if possible. Like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fruits: ["apple", "orange", "banana", "apple"]
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(this.state.fruits[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build the name of the index.

Here is one example:

```js
state = {
        fruit_1: 'apple',
        fruit_2: 'orange',
        fruit_3: 'bannana',
        fruit_4: 'apple',
}

for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(state[`fruit_${i}`]);
}
```

In your code you would use:

```
console.log(this.state[`fruit_${i}`]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop on the state directly:

```js
var state = {
  fruit_1: 'apple',
  fruit_2: 'orange',
  fruit_3: 'bannana',
  fruit_4: 'apple',
};

for (var key in state) {
  console.log(state[key]);
}
```